# Outputting a table to a template

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-orm

I recently began to study Django and cannot understand how to correctly implement the template (table)
I have a model:
She has ties to Company and bank.

```
class BankAccount(models.Model):
company = models.ForeignKey('Company.Company', null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Фирма',
                            related_name='company')
bank = models.ForeignKey('Bank', null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Банк', related_name='bank')
login_bank = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Логин', null=False)
password_bank = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Пароль', null=False)

date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
balance = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
```

In the template I want to display a table where all firms / banks will be displayed at the intersection of these columns and rows, a value from this model will appear.
I've been looking for an answer for 5 days and

|  | Company1 | Company2 | Company3 | Company4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bank1 | Balance(Company1/Bank1) | Balance(Company2/Bank1) | Balance(Company/Bank1) | Balance(Company4/Bank1) |
| Bank2 | Balance(Company1/Bank2) | .... | .... | .... |
| Bank3 | Balance(Company1/Bank3) | .... | .... | .... |

I tried the example template below, thanks
@Linh Nguyen

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
        <tr>
            <th> </th>
            {% for company in companies %}
                <th>{{ company.name }}</th>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
        {% for bank in banks %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{bank.name}} </td>
                {% for company in companies %}
                    {% for account in bank_accounts %}
                        {% if account.company_id == company.id and bank.id == account.bank_id %}
                            <td>{{account}}</td>
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                {% endfor %}
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}

    </table>



context = {
            'companies': Company.objects.all().order_by('id'),
            'banks': Bank.objects.all().order_by('id'),
            'bank_accounts': BankAccount.objects.all()
        }
```

But the result is still not desired. One firm can have 2 and 4 accounts in the table of accounts (bank_account).
and if the company does not have all 4 accounts, the data no longer match.If you add {% else%}, then the table breaks completely.
[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7iknj.png)

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="row">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <tr>
                <th> </th>
                {% for company in companies %}
                    <th>{{ company.name }}</th>
                {% endfor %}
            </tr>
            {% for bank in banks %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{bank.name}} </td>
                    {% for company in companies %}
                       <td>
                           {% for account in bank_accounts %}

                                {% if account.company_id == company.id and bank.id == account.bank_id%}
                                    {{account}}
                                {% endif %}

                            {% endfor %}
                       </td>
                    {% endfor %}
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}

        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Finally it worked out!

Comment: it seems like you have the logic wrong for the IF statement, please put <td> outside of the if condition

Comment: Unfortunately, even if you remove this IF statement, the picture does not change in any way (((

Comment: i don't mean by removing the if statement, if you look at the template i wrote the td tag is outside of the if, so that when it not match it will have an empty td

Comment: if you put the td tag inside the div if it not match the td will not be generated and the order will of course be wrong

Comment: my if statement if equivalent to {% if  %}
                            <td>{{account}}</td> {% else %} <td></td> <--- empty td
                        {% endif %}

Comment: there must be a case where you have empty td right? every td can't have the correct if

Comment: `<td>
    {% if account.company_id == company.id and bank.id == account.bank_id%}
        {{account}}
    {% endif %}
</td>`   
[link](https://imgur.com/0agrz06)

Comment: @Linh Nguyen  You are the best I love you, thank you very much. You really helped me out. May God grant you health, take care of yourself. Thank you thank you thank you

Comment: glad it helped you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it only come down to how you handle the logic in the looping:
in your view you have the querysets for all the banks, companies and bank accounts
view.py:

```
context = {
       'companies': Company.objects.all(),
       'banks': Bank.objects.all(),
       'bank_accounts': BankAccount.objects.all()
   }
```

template.html:

```
<table style="width:100%">
   <tr>
       {% for company in companies %}
       <th>{{ company.name }}</th>
       {% endfor %}       
   </tr>
   {% for bank in banks %}
   <tr>
      {% for company in companies %}
        {% for bank_account in bank_accounts %}
          <td>
            {% if bank_account.company  == company %}
               Balance({{ company.name }}/{{ bank.name }})
            {% endif %}
          </td>
        {% endfor %}
      {% endfor %}
   </tr>
   {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Comment: Your answer is very close to my wish. But still not that. I attach a screenshot of your code [link](https://ibb.co/54bLH7J)

Comment: @DickDikins you just need to display other attributes, too. This is just an example of how you should implement it.

Comment: yes this is just an example to show you how to handle the logic, as i don't have your database or your intention flow i can't replicate what you want, but i can show you how to do it

Comment: OOO then thank you very much for the tip, then I went on to try

Comment: what else is missing from your logic to my solution? if it's just attribute i already created the loop logic, you can replace the attribute within it

Comment: And if I'm not mistaken, please correct me. But adding three models to the context and passing them to the template will create many queries in the database?

Comment: yes, but you can limit the query by filtering them by login user or any page related data, if you have alot of data record then you should look into pagination of django, it will limit amount of record per page

Comment: Thanks, I haven't gotten to this yet. But the goal is to display all the data on one page for analysis. But since my Bankaccount model has a relationship with two other tables, it might be worth considering some kind of magic query in the database (Postgres)? For example, using "select_related", will this get just all the table data and reduce the number of queries?

Answer (score 0):

First, you should implement your view function like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from models import BackAccount

def get_bank_accounts(request):

accounts = BankAccount.objects.all()

context = {
    'accounts': accounts,
}
return render(request, 'accounts.html', context)
```

So, that way you send all accounts to the template. And the way you use them in `accounts.html` like this:

```
{% for account in accounts %}
  {{ account.bank }}
  {{ account.company }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but the question is how to pass the context to the template, I understand. I have a question with the implementation of it. It turns out that you have to loop through three qeurysets. But I cannot understand how to implement this.

Comment: @DickDikins The render method handles passing the context to the template.

Comment: I know thank you very much. Most likely, the problem is not with passing the context to the template, but with displaying it through the "for" loop

Comment: @DickDikins okay, got it. Your question is not about Django exactly. Next time, be careful with the tags.

Comment: I apologize for any inconvenience. But I thought templates had to do with django. Ok I'll take that into account, I apologize for wasting your time

Comment: @DickDikins apologizing is not needed. You are new and every newcomer makes mistakes, I made much worse stuff, it is so normal. I am just informing you about it, so you can find the answers you need faster and better. This is the way you gonna learn, never apologize for learning.

Comment: Thank you very much for your understanding. May the power be with you….